# Javascript error on Magento - Registry Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

We have a JavaScript error on our website (http://www.sointeriors.co.uk) and we are experiencing frequent add to cart errors which may or may not be associated with the error but either way we need it fixing so we can rule it out as causing the add to cart error.

Anyway I'm not good with JavaScript, the error in Firebug is as follows:

Error

> TypeError: registry is undefined ... line 540 of hello.jquery.js

Code

```
var respondersForEvent=registry.get(eventName);

if(Object.isUndefined(respondersForEvent)){
    respondersForEvent=[];
    registry.set(eventName,respondersForEvent);
}
```

Does this error mean anything to someone who knows JavaScript or can anyone tell me what needs to be done to correct this? It's appearing on every page of the website.